# 12.04 Nvidia driver makes system run really slow.....

Tags: drivers, 12.04, nvidia

Hello i have tried to install Nvidia drivers for my GPU from the Hardware Additional Drivers section.
i tried all that was on the list. 
when i reboot to make the driver active, computer logs in and then it goes really slow. sometimes it would freeze. 
then unfreeze so i can move my mouse. 
i click then have to wait a minute to get a reaction.

any help yall? thanks

quality standards are killing me here.

Comment: enter this in terminal lspci -v and post the output related to the video card here.

Comment: I have 2 Nvidia solutions, One is onboard (6200) and the other is discrete (8800 GTS). nothing is plugged in the onboard gpu.

Answer (score 2):

see my link here - same issue. In essence the latest NVidia drivers are borked and make your system really unstable. If you uninstall them you'll automatically revert to the noveau drivers which work fine but don't have 3d capability. I've done that while waiting for NVidia to sort our their stuff...

To uninstall nvidia drivers from terminal:

sudo apt-get purge nvidia* 
followed by
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg

https://askubuntu.com/questions/126843/clean-install-of-12-04-results-in-constant-freezes-x-org-suspected

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem today. After upgrading from (K)Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 (I know it's a bit late) X did not really react anymore. It was extremely slow, absolutely unusable.

After de-installing the Nvidia drivers it ran smoothly, but the graphics resolution was intolerably small.

I tried all kinds of remedies suggested anywhere on the web, but nothing helped.

Only installing the 304 version of the Nvidia drivers actually helped. All other, like 96, 173, nvidia-current or 310 did not do the trick. Most of them did not work at all, so that the respective nvidia-settings program always told me I was not using Nvidia drivers at all, although they were the only installed ones and there was an X screen in front of me. The programs were just lying.

So, my recommendation is the 304 (experimental) driver.

And my recommendation for the Nvidia and Ubuntu people is to test the software just a little bit and refrain from releasing buggy drivers! It's a pain in the butt!